# Get contacts from android device filter by account type

Tags: android, android-contacts

I writen a application contact sync. It sync contact from server to device. When sync done with user haduy@lvsolution.vn, i want get all contact's haduy user. But it get all contact in device, don't filter by haduy user. I only want get contact of haduy@lvsolution account.

```
public void getContact()
{
    String phone = null;
    String name = null;
    listContact.clear();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                   phone = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                }
                Contact contact = new Contact(name,phone);
                listContact.add(contact);
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810795/filter-contacts-except-groups-of-account-type may be helpful

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830 and modify the `selection` so that it is `ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " in (?, ?) and " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?"`also append your account type to `selectionArgs`